# Godot 4.0.b7: Attach mouse-entered signal via code to dynamically generated CollisionShape2D

Tags: signals, godot

I have an array of dynamically generated 'planets' that need to be able to interact with the mouse. I have been trying to use the new Godot 4 signals format, but no joy yet.

The following code works correctly:

```
func _ready():
    for planet in planets:
        var planet_collision_shape = CollisionShape2D.new()
        planet_collision_shape.shape = CircleShape2D.new()
        planet_collision_shape.shape.radius = 27.5
        planet_collision_shape.position = Vector2(planet._coord[0], planet._coord[1])
        add_child(planet_collision_shape)
        planet._body = planet_collision_shape
```

But attempts to implement a signal with the following code generates an error code of:

Invalid get index 'mouse_entered' (on base: 'CircleShape2D').

```
        planet._body.shape.mouse_entered.connect(self._on_mouse_entered)
```

The node tree is nested as follows, with the dynamically generated nodes attaching to the Camera2D.

Node2D -> CanvasLayer -> Camera2D

********** EDIT **********

@ Theraot: Well, I genuinely thought I was close to a solution before your comment, but it seems that my code has confused even you. Here is the full script:

```
extends Node2D


var mouse_entered

@onready var camera = $"."

var planets = Global.planets
var zoom_minimum = Vector2(.5, .5)
var zoom_maximum = Vector2(2.5, 2.5)
var zoom_speed = Vector2(.1, .1)
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO


func _ready():
    for planet in planets:
        var planet_collision_shape = CollisionShape2D.new()
        planet_collision_shape.shape = CircleShape2D.new()
        planet_collision_shape.shape.radius = 27.5
        planet_collision_shape.position = Vector2(planet._coord[0], planet._coord[1])
        add_child(planet_collision_shape)
        planet._body = planet_collision_shape
#       #planet._body.mouse_entered.connect(self._on_mouse_entered)


func _on_mouse_entered():
    print("BUMP")


func _draw():
    for planet in planets:
        var center = Vector2(planet._coord[0] + velocity.x, planet._coord[1] + velocity.y)
        var size = planet._texture.get_size()
        var rect = Rect2(center - size * .5, size)
        draw_texture_rect(planet._texture, rect, false)
        planet._body.position = center


func update():
    queue_redraw()
    

func _process(_delta):
    if Input.is_physical_key_pressed(65):
        velocity.x -= 10
    if Input.is_physical_key_pressed(68):
        velocity.x += 10
    if Input.is_physical_key_pressed(87):
        velocity.y -= 10
    if Input.is_physical_key_pressed(83):
        velocity.y += 10
    update()


func _input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if event.is_pressed():
            if event.button_index == 4:
                if camera.zoom > zoom_minimum:
                    camera.zoom -= zoom_speed
                    print(camera.zoom)
            if event.button_index == 5:
                if camera.zoom < zoom_maximum:
                    camera.zoom += zoom_speed
                    print(camera.zoom)
```

At runtime the tree looks as follows:

[image]

The above code results in planet icons that move with their respective collision shapes as follows:

[image]

Since I have the collision shapes where I want them I belived that my next step was to connect a signal so I could tell when the mouse was over a planet. Any advice on how to proceed from here greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first problem: The collisionShape does not have a mouse entered event. A collisionObject does (e.g an Area2D or kinematicBody2D which need a collisionshape as a child).
Second: I don't think the syntax is correct to connect a signal. And Third: Why are you adding the ConnectionShapes to your camera node and not as a child of your planet node?

Comment: Presumably you want the `mouse_entered` signal from a `CollisionObject2D` (which is either an `Area2D` or a `PhysicsBody2D`… And the `PhysicsBody2D` is either a `CharacterBody2D` or a `RigidBody2D` or a `StaticBody2D`). But I suspect you don't have a  `CollisionObject2D`, because you would add the `CollisionShape2D` as child of the corresponding `CollisionObject2D`, not children of the `Camera2D`. Do you need help creating `CollisionObject2D`s or are you trying to use `PhysicsServer2D`?

Comment: @Bugfish being the question about Godot 4, it is not `KinematicBody2D` but `CharacterBody2D`, and the signal connection syntax would be correct.

Comment: @ Theraot: Edits above. As indicated in the full script and screenshots I have neither a CollisionObject2D or PhysicsServer2D. I don't know if it matters, but the planets are static in space and will only be interacting with the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have surely already figured out by the errors, neither `CollisionShape2D` nor `CircleShape2D`. We can approach this a few ways.

---

### The easy Godot way™

You would make a `Planet` scene, with these `Node`s

```
Planet
├ CollisionShape2D
└ Sprite2D
```

The root of the scene (i.e. `Planet`) would be a `StaticBody2D` (or perhaps a some other kind of body), and it would have the `mouse_entered` signal.

The `CollisionShape2D` would have the `CircleShape2D` you want set from the editor. But don't position it. You will position the `StaticBody2D` instead.

And the `Sprite2D` would be responsible for rendering the texture. *So with this approach would not be using `_draw` to render the textures.*

Since both the `CollisionShape2D` and `Sprite2D` are children of the `StaticBody2D` (`Planet`), when it moves they move with it.

Once you have the scene, it would be saved to a scene file (e.g. a ".tscn" file) which you can instantiate multiple times, and set its properties (change its position and change the texture of the `Sprite2D`) either from code or in the editor (you can set editable children from the context menu in the scene panel, which will allow you to change the `Sprite2D` texture).

So, as you can see **this approach requires no code for the planets**.

---

### The hard Godot way™

Using `_draw` has its advantages. For once you don't need to instantiate as many objects (since you don't have any `Sprite2D`).

But what about physics? That is the issue here… You don't have a physics body that can do a point-shape intersection/collision which the mouse signals need…

So, you could do this the hard way. We can get mouse input events in `_input` and check if they enter any planet. *Thankfully you only need point-circle collision, which is easy.* It would be something like this:

```
func _input(event:InputEvent) -> void:
    if not event is InputEventMouse:
        return

    var mouse_event := event as InputEventMouse

    for planet in planets:
        var center = Vector2(planet._coord[0] + velocity.x, planet._coord[1] + velocity.y)
        var radius = planet._texture.get_size().x * 0.5 # 27.5
        if mouse_event.position.distance_to(center) < radius:
             # the mouse pointer is over the planet
             break
```

If you want actual signals you can do it like this:

```
signal mouse_entered()
signal mouse_exited()


var _mouse_is_inside:bool

func _input(event:InputEvent) -> void:
    if not event is InputEventMouse:
        return

    var mouse_event := event as InputEventMouse

    var is_inside := false
    for planet in planets:
        var center = Vector2(planet._coord[0] + velocity.x, planet._coord[1] + velocity.y)
        var radius = planet._texture.get_size().x * 0.5 # 27.5
        if mouse_event.position.distance_to(center) < radius:
             is_inside = true
             break

    if _mouse_is_inside != is_inside:
        _mouse_is_inside = is_inside
        if _mouse_is_inside:
            emit_signal("mouse_entered")
        else:
            emit_signal("mouse_exited")
```

---

### The harder Godot way™

If the motivation to use `_draw` is optimization. Then we can do much better than the approaches above. And we do that by using the `RenderingServer` for drawing and the `PhysicsServer2D` et.al. for physics. In other words, we can use a lower level API. **This approach does not use `Node`s for the planets at all.** *You probably don't need this unless you will have planets in the thousands.*

We can create a physics body like this:

```
body=PhysicsServer2D.body_create()
```

And you are responsible for freeing it like this:

```
PhysicsServer2D.free_rid(body)
```

My recommendation is to use `_enter_tree` for initialization, and `_exit_tree` for tear down.

You need to assign a space to your body, so we use the one from your `Node2D` (where the script is running):

```
PhysicsServer2D.body_set_space(body, get_world_2d().space)
```

And you want to give a shape to the body, which is something like this (here `shape` would be the `CircleShape2D`):

```
var disabled := false
PhysicsServer2D.body_add_shape(body, shape.get_rid(), Transform2D.IDENTITY, disabled)
```

If you prefer to not use `CircleShape2D`, you can use `circle_shape_create` and configure it with `shape_set_data`:

```
var radius := 27.5
var shape_rid := PhysicsServer2D.circle_shape_create()
PhysicsServer2D.shape_set_data(shape_rid, radius)
```

To position the body you do this:

```
PhysicsServer2D.body_set_state(body, PhysicsServer2D.BODY_STATE_TRANSFORM, global_transform)
```

And for the visual part, create a canvas item:

```
var ci_rid := RenderingServer.canvas_item_create()
```

We are going to make it a child of your `Node2D` (where the script is running):

```
RenderingServer.canvas_item_set_parent(ci_rid, get_canvas_item())
```

We can `load` our `Texture` and set it:

```
var texture:Texture = load("res://icon.png")
texture.reference()
var texture_rid := texture.get_rid()
```

This is intended to be a workaround to prevent `Texture` being freed due not being references to it, and thus invalidating the rid. Another way to go about it is to make a copy:

```
var texture:Texture = load("res://icon.png")
var image:Image = texture.get_data()
var texture_rid := RenderingServer.texture_2d_create(image)
```

And you can add the texture, and of course position the canvas item:

```
RenderingServer.canvas_item_add_texture_rect(ci_rid, rect, texture_rid)
RenderingServer.canvas_item_set_transform(ci_rid, Transform2D.IDENTITY)
```

And you can keep calling `PhysicsServer2D.body_set_state` and `RenderingServer.canvas_item_set_transform` to move the planet.

Ah, and you need to know if the mouse enters… Once again we will resource to `_input`, this time we use `intersect_point` to find what is below the mouse pointer, which gives us an `Array` of objects, and we look for one that matches the rid of our body. If we find it then the mouse pointer is inside:

```
signal mouse_entered()
signal mouse_exited()


var _mouse_is_inside:bool


func _input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if not event is InputEventMouse:
        return

    var mouse_event := event as InputEventMouse

    var viewport := get_viewport()
    var position:Vector2 = viewport.get_canvas_transform().affine_inverse() * mouse_event.position
    var query := PhysicsPointQueryParameters2D.new()
    query.position = position
    var objects := get_world_2d().direct_space_state.intersect_point(query, 32)
    var is_inside := false
    for object in objects:
        if object.rid == body:
            is_inside = true
            break

    if _mouse_is_inside != is_inside:
        _mouse_is_inside = is_inside
        if _mouse_is_inside:
            emit_signal("mouse_entered")
        else:
            emit_signal("mouse_exited")
```

*Note: this code is adapted from Godot 3 to 4 because I haven't got that deep into Godot 4 yet. If it gives you problems let me know.*